# Ways to get the payment from international client

Tags: india, international-transfer

I just started a Pvt Ltd company in India and have few International clients from Singapore and Thailand. We are into services.

1. What is the best way to get the payment.
2. Do I need Import Export Code (IEC)  of something like this if I'm planning to create some software solution and planning to sell it as a product.

Comment: I think a region tag would be helpful for this question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to get the payment.

It depends on the amounts, you can set-up a paypal if the amounts are very small or use a Credit Card gateway to get funds. If the amounts are large, ask the customer to pay directly by transfer to your Bank Account in India.

> Do I need Import Export Code (IEC) of something like this if I'm planning to create some software solution and planning to sell it as a product.

That depends on the nature of business. Please consult a CA

Comment: +1 for PayPal or some other similar form of online payment. With all due respect, I suspect the rider "if the amounts are very small" to be true, since it is unlikely someone would have to ask such a question if they were not small!

Comment: Hi Cosmic, Thanks for you reply.
We have never done international business which involves international business. It our first venture in this regard. As suggested I will have my CA and other to help me but it was out of my curiosity of discovering things on my own taking help of online materials that prompted me to post this.